# why form is not submitting with javascript

Tags: javascript

[form is not submitting please tell me about possible answer]

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOGHj.png[2]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIuDt.png[3]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOGHj.png%5B2%5D:https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIuDt.png%5B3%5D): https://i.stack.imgur.com/bswEW.png

Comment: Why did you not read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ? 
The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, **and the shortest code necessary** to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, not as pictures of text.  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 1):

you should pass a function as a second parameter to `addEventListener` function:

```js
form.addEventListener('submit', () => {
Validate()
})
```